# How to generate Password reset link through Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I’m trying to send a password reset email to a user through a cloud function using the generatePasswordResetLink method. However, when the URL is generated and I click on it, I get this error:

```
{
  "authEmulator": {
    "error": "missing newPassword query parameter",
    "instructions": "To reset the password for meu@email.com, send an HTTP GET request to the following URL.",
    "instructions2": "You may use a web browser or any HTTP client, such as curl.",
    "urlTemplate": "http://localhost:9099/emulator/action?mode=resetPassword&lang=en&oobCode=94dZV63_qB1CRcmofnM9bpCD0pLRxqZ4sTVPzwERpMEzWqKKu_9X2d&apiKey=fake-api-key&continueUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fmeu.site%2Fh0qLORGQe4cuoqSoxcA6&newPassword=NEW_PASSWORD_HERE"
  }
}
```

I’m trying to run this on the emulator.

This is the method:
`admin.auth().generatePasswordResetLink(user.email, {url: "https://meu.site"})`

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe password reset just isn't supported by the emulator?  Or it's broken?  File an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools).

Comment: Hey @DougStevenson that's exactly it. I did a long shot and sent it to production and it worked perfectly. Will do that. Thanks bud